# Escape quotes in django's trans method

Tags: django, string, internationalization, escaping

I'm trying to internationalize my webpages by using the `{% trans "string" %}` method in django.

However I get an error when I try to use quotes in the string. I've already tried to escape them with a backslash with no luck.

How can I escape something like this:

```
{% trans "foo's is like "foo"." %}
```

As I said, this doesn't work:

```
{% trans "foo\'s is like \"foo\"." %}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`blocktrans`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktranslate-template-tag) instead.

###### Example

```
{% blocktranslate %}Just an example block to translate with {{value}} and text.{% endblocktranslate %}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: Note that `blocktrans` and `blocktranslate` are aliases of each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ _("foo's is like \"foo\".") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `{% translate %}` and the `{% blocktranslate %}` template tags are generally meant to be used with HTML. So you could simply escape them as you would in HTML:

```html
{% blocktranslate %}foo's is like &quot;foo&quot;{% endblocktranslate %}
<br>
{% trans "foo's is like &quot;foo&quot;" %}
```

Assuming that the language is set to the default language (English), this would send this HTML to the browser:

```html
foo's is like &quot;foo&quot;
<br>
foo's is like &quot;foo&quot;
```

The user would see on the screen this text:

> foo's is like "foo"
>
> foo's is like "foo"

By the way, the template tag `{% translate %}` is just an alias for `{% trans %}`, and `{% blocktranslate %}` is just an alias for `{% blocktrans %}`.