# How to escape a single quote within trans when the line is already wrapped with single quotes?

Tags: django

```
{% trans 'Enter your friend's name and email below, and click "send invite" to invite your friend.' %}
```

The line is already wrapped with single quotes and double quote are also utilised in the line.  So how can I escape `friend's` here?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape quotes in django's trans method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374416/escape-quotes-in-djangos-trans-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually found it.  Using blocktrans allows you to have anything in there, mixed and matched. :)

```
{% blocktrans %}Enter your friend's name and email below, and click "send invite" to invite your friend.{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Well, I clearly agree upon this being the "Django way", but unfortunately it also breaks the syntax highlighting in my editor (I use Sublime 2, but it should be the same for every editor unless you create special rules for that tag).

Comment: I think that has to do with Sublime. I am using Aptana Studio 3.0 and the editor is fine with it.

Answer (score 5):

```
{% trans 'Enter your friend&#39;s name and email below, and click "send invite" to invite your friend.' %}
```